# how to change the value of a label in childForm from Another form button

Tags: vb.net, containers

need a little help i cant seem to change the value/text of a label when im using this method to open another form.

i have 3 form (form1, form2, form3) form1 is my main form which has a panel which i want the form 2 to appear/show(which i manage to do). then in form 2 i have a label and a button(to open form 3 using showdialog which is working). now in form 3 i have a button that will change the text of the label in form2 but its not working here the code.

form1

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim myForm As New Form

    Public Sub openChildForm(childform As Form)

        If Not IsDBNull(myForm) Then myForm.Close() ' this will close active form

        myForm = childform ' store childform in myform
        childform.TopLevel = False
        childform.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None ' remove border to be put in panelChildForm
        childform.Dock = DockStyle.Fill ' make childform dockstyle to fill to remove excess space if there are
        Panel1.Controls.Add(childform) ' add childform as a control of panel1
        Panel1.Tag = childform
        childform.BringToFront()
        childform.Show()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        openChildForm(New Form2)
    End Sub
End Class
```

form2

```
Public Class Form2
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Form3.ShowDialog()
    End Sub
End Class
```

form3

```
Public Class Form3
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Form2.Label1.Text = "NEW FORM 2"
    End Sub
End Class
```

this is what it looks like

[image]

Comment: First guess, you're updating the properties of the default form instance rather than the actual instance of the form you're looking at.  Maybe this might clear things up https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/developing-apps/development-with-my/default-object-instances-provided-by-my-forms-and-my-webservices

Comment: Why are you using forms like that in the first place? You should be using user controls, not forms.

Comment: Given that you're calling `ShowDialog` on `Form3` from `Form2`, there should be no need to do anything on `Form2` until `Form3` closes. At that point, `Form2` should be getting the required data from one or more properties of `Form3` and updating its own `Label`. `Form3` should not even know or have to know that `Form2` exists.

Answer (score 0):

form2

```
Public Class Form2
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        My.Forms.Form3.ShowDialog()
        Label1.Text = My.Forms.Form3.str
    End Sub

End Class
```

form3

```
Public Class Form3
    Public str As String
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        str = "NEW FORM 2"
    End Sub
End Class
```